# Node js console.log is not showing anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to scrap a webpage using node js.I think I've written the code and was able to run it without any errors but the problem is the console doesn't print anything no matter what I do.It is not showing any errors. What's the reason?

Here is the content that I want to scrap:
https://paste.ee/r/b3yrn

```
var fs         = require('fs');
var request    = require('request');
var cheerio    = require('cheerio');

var htmlString = fs.readFileSync('scrap.html').toString();
var $          = cheerio.load(htmlString);
var json = [];

$('body > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr').each(function(i, element) {
    json.push({});
    json[i].range = $(this).text().trim();

});


console.log(json);
```

Comment: Probably `json` is empty. You should check if your selector finds anything. Or try to do a `console.log(json.length);` to see if the array is empty or not.

Comment: nope. I even tried to print it inside the .each like console.log($(this).text()); but still it is not working and not showing any errors

Comment: If the selector won't find anything then a `console.log` inside of the each won't be called because there is no element. So the first test would be to do a `console.log(json.length);`  instead of a  `console.log(json);`

Comment: the selector and each function works perfectly inside google chrome's console by importing the jquery library

Comment: Is is great that it does work in the browser, but the browser is not `node.js` and not  `cheerio`. So why don't you just replace the `console.log(json);`  with `console.log(json.length);` and tell us if you see a `0`  or another number in the console, so that we can narrow down the problem?

Comment: @t.niese
Go to this page
http://www.infopark.in/company_vacancy_all.php


import the jquery library by pasting this
var script = document.createElement('script');script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);


and past this 
$('body > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr').each(function(i, element) {
console.log(element);
});

it works perfectly!

Comment: In the source there a two `body`  elements, and I guess `cheerio` won't correct that error and while browser does. But then my assumption that your selector won't find anything (in _cheerio_)  is still the same.

Comment: I removed the first body tag from my local file and still it doesn't work!?

Comment: I asked you to do one simple thing to narrow down the problem and you are not able to do that, so it is not possible to help you. And because of that I already wasted to much time with this question, that I could have used with other questions to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be sure that your `console.log` work correctly just try it like that :

```js
console.log('starting');//<--------------------------------------- added line

var fs         = require('fs');
var request    = require('request');
var cheerio    = require('cheerio');

var htmlString = fs.readFileSync('scrap.html').toString();
var $          = cheerio.load(htmlString);
var json = [];

console.log('htmlString : ' + htmlString );//<-------------------- added line


$('body > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr').each(function(i, element) {
    json.push({});
    json[i].range = $(this).text().trim();

});

console.log('Elements in json : ' + json.length);//<-------------- added line
console.log(json);
```

If this don't produce anything on the **server-side**, so yes we can confirm that your `console.log` don't work as expected, else it works and the problem come from other things !

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am facing this unusual problem as well.... When my app loads i have couple of things logged on the console which work but after  the app is started nothing gets logged on the console but all my network requests work as intended but where i have put console.log does not seem to work on Linux environment.